# What does fixed EXIF mean?

Tags: metadata, lens-mount, canon-600d, minolta

I'm buying a lens adapter for my new Minolta AF 500mm reflex lens and one that I have found specifically states that the EXIF is fixed at 50mm F1.4.

I'm not sure what this means for my photos in the end but if anyone could give me a hint I'd appreciate it.

Also if anyone has some lens adapter recommendations since this seems to be a popular lens so someone might have found a good fit that would be great. I'm trying to fit it to my Canon 600D.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That means that fake lens data is transmitted to the camera. The camera therefore records that it took a photo with a 50mm F/1.4, probably always at F/1.4 regardless of which lens you actually have mounted on the adapter. Some adapters do not send any data and show *Unknown Lens* instead.

Now since you are asking this, I am guessing you do not look much at the metadata from images, so the fact that it is faked should have little impact to you.

The only thing you should care for is to deactivate any lens-based correction in-camera since that would apply the wrong profile given it does not know what lens is mounted. This applies to optical distortion correction, vignetting correction and chromatic aberration removal. You can still use HTP and the like which apply to the image the same way regardless of the lens.

Comment: So there won't be too much of a visual impact, and will stay as "true" to the viewfinder as possible?

Comment: No visual impact at all. EXIF is just metadata. The viewfinder shows the view through the lens and that is unaffected.

Comment: Would it not affect metering? Or is the lens already stopped down during metering when using this lens/adapter?

Answer (score 0):

EXchangeable Image File, is what it stands for. The other answers tell you what it means in your case. Mine is just to give you an exact definition of the acronymn. It stores several fields of information in the jpeg file, such as author, image size, dimensions, copyright, ... If you want an easy way to see the EXIF data in a jpeg, highlight the file (Windows), right click, properties, details. There you go, all the metadata, or EXIF data.